# RestAPI Authentication for requests

Tags: java, node.js, rest, stateless

I have recently started studying Restful API. However I've come to a halt regarding sessions. My concern is if I use Restful I'm supposed to not have a session from what I've understood. Now, as an example suppose in my app there are certain actions which requires user be logged in first. How will the server validate if the user logged in or not without maintaining any session? How does Facebook do this? For every request does it not check whether the user is logged in in case of fetching sensitive info? Can't get my head around this.

Comment: There are a number of possible strategies.  For example, you can have an auth process that generates a token and then you require that token to be sent with every API request that requires credentials (either in a custom header. in the query string or in a cookie which is just another form of header) and the server has some ability to verity that token (typically using some sort of crypto operation) without maintaining any sort of heavy-weight session.

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!